# How handle this error situation related to call a method that create a new object on Firestore AFTER that a file is saved into the Storage?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, firebase-storage

I am not so into Angular and Firebase and I have the following problem.

I have the following code that handle the entire cycle of the user registration. It partially works but I have a problem that I will try to explain in details (probably because I still have some difficulties with functional programming...):

```ts
createUser(user, file) {
  console.log(user);

  if(user.password != user.password_confirmation) {
    let passwordError: any = new Object();
    passwordError["message"] = "Inserted password and inserted password confirmation are different";
    this.eventAuthError.next(passwordError);
  }
  else {
    this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
      .then( userCredential => {
        this.newUser = user;
        console.log(userCredential);
        userCredential.user.updateProfile( {
          displayName: user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName
        });

        this.uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore(file);


        this.insertUserData(userCredential, this.downloadURL)
          .then(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          });
      })
      .catch( error => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(typeof error);
        this.eventAuthError.next(error);    // Emit the event passing the error object
      });
    }
}

uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore(fileToBeUploaded) {
  var n = Date.now();
  const filePath = `user_avatar/${n}`;
  const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);

  const task = this.storage.upload(`user_avatar/${n}`, fileToBeUploaded);
  task
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
        this.downloadURL.subscribe(url => {
          if (url) {
            this.fb = url;
          }
          console.log(this.fb);
        });
      })
    )
    .subscribe(url => {
      if (url) {
        console.log(url);
      }
    });

    return this.fb

}

insertUserData(userCredential: firebase.auth.UserCredential, userAvatar) {

  let userObg = {
        name: this.newUser.firstName,
        surname: this.newUser.lastName,
        complete_name: this.newUser.firstName + " " + this.newUser.lastName,
        email: this.newUser.email,
        role: this.newUser.ruolo_utente,
        avatar: userAvatar
      };

  console.log("USER OBJECT: ", userObg);

  return this.db.doc(`Users/${userCredential.user.uid}`).set(userObg);
}
```

Basically it does the following things:

1. The `createUser()` take a **user** object that have to be saved into a FireStore collection and a **file** parameter that is an image that have to be saved into the Firebase Storage.
2. First it calls the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` that create a new user into the Firebase Authentication service using username and password (it works fine).
3. If the user is correctly created it enter into the **then()** and it call the `uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore()` method that is used to upload the image file on Firebase Storage.
4. Then it call the `insertUserData()` method that create and save a new object related to the current user into FireStore.

My problem happens between the poin 3 and 4. In details the file is correctly saved into the Firebase Storage but it seems to me that it is an asyncronous task and so it take some time before return the URL related to this file into Firebase Storage. It take time but in the meantime the `insertUserData()` is started so here this URL field (that I have to save in my object) is undefined.

What could be a smart way to wait untill the file URL is "returned"? Maybe I have not to return anything but a good thing to do is to put the call to `insertUserData()` (that insert into FireStore) into the `uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore()` method after that the URL is retrieved, here:

```ts
this.downloadURL.subscribe(url => {
    if (url) {
        this.fb = url;
        // I PUT THE CALL TO HERE
    }
    console.log(this.fb);
});
```

What could be a smart solution for this issue?

Comment: For code like this, it's very helpful if you learn JavaScript/TypeScript async/await syntax, as it makes dealing with series of promises much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `.pipe()` your streams, or you'll never get to sync them.

`uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore` should `return` the upload stream:

```js
return this.storage.upload(`user_avatar/${n}`, fileToBeUploaded)
  .snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(switchMap(() => fileRef.getDownloadURL());
```

Then, in your `createUser` you can use it:

```js
this.uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore(file).subscribe(downloadURL =>
  this.insertUserData(userCredential, downloadURL)
    .then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    });
  );
```